# Cannot mount volume as non-root using securityContext

Tags: kubernetes

According to [the kubernetes doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/), `securityContext.fsGroup` can be used to specify the permissions of a mounted volume:

> Since fsGroup field is specified, all processes of the container are also part of the supplementary group ID 2000. The owner for volume /data/demo and any files created in that volume will be Group ID 2000.

I can't get that feature to work.

*test.yaml*

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: task-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /home/docker/mypv2
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: task-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1001
    runAsGroup: 1001
    fsGroup: 1001
  volumes:
    - name: myvolume
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: task-pv-claim
  containers:
    - name: mycontainer
      image: myimage:latest
      command: ['sleep', 'infinity']
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/mytest"
          name: myvolume
```

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN groupadd --gid 1001 mygroup
RUN useradd --uid 1001 --gid mygroup --shell /bin/bash --create-home myuser
```

When I run a shell on the pod, I'm correctly logged as user 1001 (`myuser`). However, the mounted volume is owned by group `root`:

```
myuser@mypod:/$ ls -la /mytest
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 12 18:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jun 12 18:49 ..
```

Tested on minikube 1.11.0 with kubernetes 1.18.0

Note: In deployment scenarios, I don't have access to the kubernetes host, so I can't run chown or chmod there.

Comment: Can you check by setting `securityContext.allowPrivilegeEscalation: false` on containers ?

Comment: @hoque I tested: no change.

Answer (score 2):

You can add **initContainers** to set proper permission

```
  initContainers:
  - name: volume-permission
    image: busybox
    command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 1001:1001 /mytest"]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: myvolume
      mountPath: /mytest
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 0
```

Comment: This approach works but it  requires running a root container, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @AurélienGasser Then change `runAsUser`, `runAsGroup` and `fsGroup` to 1000

Comment: @hariK I'm trying to run containers as user 1001 exclusively

Comment: @hoque works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

It because you're mounting a directory from the host which owns by root. If you change the ownership of the host directory to 1001, it'll update the permission of mounted directory on container.

```
$ ls -la /home/docker/mypv/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root   40 Jun 12 21:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 docker docker 80 Jun 12 21:41 ..

$ kubectl exec -it mypod bash
myuser@mypod:/$ ls -la /mytest/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   40 Jun 12 21:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jun 12 21:45 ..
```

Update ownership at host

```
$ sudo chown docker:docker mypv
$ ls -la /home/docker/mypv/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 docker docker 40 Jun 12 21:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 docker docker 80 Jun 12 21:41 ..

$ myuser@mypod:/$ ls -la /mytest/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 1000 1000   40 Jun 12 21:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jun 12 21:45 ..
myuser@mypod:/$
```

Comment: I should have specified that in deployment scenarios, I don't have access to the kubernetes host, so I can't run `chown` or `chmod` there. I'll update the question.